# (py-cord) Why does `bot.add_command` not work when using `discord.Bot()`?

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I switched from commands.Bot to discord.Bot to get slash commands as well as prefixed commands. It is giving the error

```py
File "/home/-/Desktop/Stuff/CODING/Discord-Bot-OrbiBot/cogs/economy.py", line 270, in setup
    bot.add_cog(Economy(bot))
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/cog.py", line 546, in add_cog
    cog = cog._inject(self)
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/cog.py", line 454, in _inject
    raise e
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/cog.py", line 448, in _inject
    bot.add_command(command)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_command'
```

Is there a different command to use?
(i am using py-cord 2.0.0b4)

Comment: It seems that pycord uses the `add_application_command()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because `discord.Bot` doesn't support prefix commands which is what `add_command()` is trying to make.

What you'd want to do is use `commands.Bot` instead, commands being imported via `from discord.ext import commands`

Comment: You didn't read the question properly. I said I switched from `commands.Bot()`

Comment: @Orbitix `commands.Bot` supports both prefix and slash commands.